# How to create a flutter notification in iOS with custom sound and icon using flutter_local_notifications plugin?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, notifications

I need to create a flutter notification in iOS using flutter_local_notifications plugin with custom sound and icon. If it is not possible with that plugin, please recommend to me a way to accomplish the task.